# Pass inline ASP databind to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button that runs a JavaScript Method which accepts a paramater:

```
function MyFunc(param)
{
    // stuff here with the value passed in
}
```

And I am calling it from my ASPX code:

```
onclientclick="if(!MyFunc('hard coded param')) return false;"
```

This works with the hard coded parameter above but I get an error that the tag is not well formed with the following

```
onclientclick="if(!MyFunc('<%# String.Concat(Eval("MyParam")) %>')) return false;"

onclientclick="if(!MyFunc(''<%# String.Concat(Eval("MyParam")) %>'')) return false;"
```

what is the correct way to format this in ASP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been in ASP.NET since the very beginning. If you have data bindings inside an attribute you need to switch to single quotes to build your attribute. I also try put the entire attribute value inside the databind block to avoid more problems.

I would code that like this:

```
 onclientclick='<%# String.Concat("if(!MyFunc(\"", Eval("Text"), "\")) return false;") %>'
```

Comment: This is the answer I went with although I had to make a change, replacing \" with &#39; to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

change `<%# String.Concat(Eval("MyParam")) %>` as `<%# String.Concat(Eval(\"MyParam\")) %>`

Comment: I've tried both of these but no luck

onclientclick="if(!MyFunc('<%# String.Concat(Eval(\"MyParam\")) %>')) return false;"

onclientclick="if(!MyFunc(''<%# String.Concat(Eval(\"MyParam\")) %>'')) return false;"

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# "if(!MyFunc(\""+ Eval("MyParam")+"\"))return false" %>'  Text="Hello"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function MyFunc(param) {
                alert(param);
            }

</script>
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.